# Laravel Consulta

Tags: laravel, orm

Hola tengo  una consulta en Laravel 5.5 que me trae lo que necesito con los datos relacionados de 2 tablas mi consulta es la siguiente:

```
$facturas = ProgramacionPagos::select('*')
            ->where([
                ['pagorealizado' , '0'], ['autorizado_cxp', '!=' , NULL]
            ])
            ->with('files')
            ->with('comments')
            ->get();
```

y si trae lo que necesito de la siguiente mandera: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es poder acceder a los valores de las tablas relacionadas. He intendado hacerlo con

```
@foreach($facturas as $k => $factura) 
$factura->files->id
```

pero me da error. Alguien que me pueda ayudar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías hacer uso de el método [**each**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-each) de las [**colecciones**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections) de Laravel, (que pienso sería lo más indicado)

```
$facturas->files->each(function($archivo, $indice){
    // Realizas lo pertinente con cada objeto $archivo
    echo $archivo->id;
});
```

O bien podrías transformar todo el objeto a un arreglo original de `PHP` y hacer lo siguiente:

```
$facturas = ProgramacionPagos::select('*')
            ->where([
                ['pagorealizado' , '0'], ['autorizado_cxp', '!=' , NULL]
            ])
            ->with('files')
            ->with('comments')
            ->get()
            ->toArray(); // Convertimos nuestra colección a un arreglo simple

// Accedemos al arreglo 'files' dentro de nuestro arreglo facturas
foreach($facturas['files'] as $indice => $archivo){
    // Realizas lo pertinente con cada objeto $archivo
    echo $archivo['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer un recorrido deberías pasearlo primero a un array con `toArray()`, algo así:

```
$facturas = ProgramacionPagos::select('*')
  ->where([
    ['pagorealizado' , '0'], ['autorizado_cxp', '!=' , NULL]
  ])
  ->with('files')
  ->with('comments')
  ->get()
  ->toArray();
```

Comment: No veo la necesidad de convertirlo a un array usando `toArray()` cuando puedes recorrer la coleción de laravel con un `each(callback())`

Comment: Qué error te está imprimiendo `$factura->files->id`? Creo que es porque estás haciendo mal el llamado, veo que dice array, entonces debería ser algo así `$factura['files']->items[0]`

Comment: Me dice 'Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.' Puedo acceder a ellos de la siguiente manera  "$factura->files[0]->id" intentare convirtiendo todo a un array y les cuento